How to extract only error message from Oracle raise_application_error in oracle apex
I am getting error in oracle apex API that i am showing in apex page using raise_application_error
Error showing now as ORA-20001- 'Sku is mapped wrongly for this order'
Currently i am getting the error message in apex screen along with ORA error message, but my requirement is to only show the error message which we got from Api not the ORA-20001
Expected output:
Sku is mapped wrongly for this order

PL/SQL Errors in Oracle APEX can be trapped/manipulated through a custom error handling function (docs). This allows consistent error behaviour throughout the application.
Here is an example that removes the ORA- code from all user-defined exceptions.
create error handling function
create the following function in pl/sql:
create or replace function APEX_ERROR_CUSTOM
    (
      p_error IN apex_error.t_error 
    )
    RETURN apex_error.t_error_result
  IS
    l_result          apex_error.t_error_result := apex_error.t_error_result();
    c_inline_with_field            constant varchar2(40):='INLINE_WITH_FIELD';  
    c_inline_in_notification       constant varchar2(40):='INLINE_IN_NOTIFICATION';      
  BEGIN 
     
    l_result := apex_error.init_error_result ( p_error => APEX_ERROR_CUSTOM.p_error );  

    -- only remove ORA error for user defined exceptions
    IF p_error.ora_sqlcode BETWEEN -20999 AND -20000 THEN
        l_result.message := REPLACE(l_result.message,'ORA'||p_error.ora_sqlcode||': ','');
    END IF;

    RETURN l_result;
  END APEX_ERROR_CUSTOM;
/

add error handling function to your application
Set the function in application definition > error handling:


This is a simple page that contains region with

a button that submits the page, i.e. runs the process
a hidden item (P4_ERROR_MESSAGE) which will contain error message

Process looks like this:
declare
  ex_sku exception;
  pragma exception_init (ex_sku, -20001);
begin
  raise_application_error(-20001, 'Sku is mapped wrongly for this order');

exception 
  when ex_sku then
    :P4_ERROR_MESSAGE := substr(sqlerrm, instr(sqlerrm, ':') + 1);
  when others then
    :P4_ERROR_MESSAGE := sqlerrm;
end;


user-defined exception is named ex_sku (name it any way you want)
pragma says which error message is related to it
executable part of this sample procedure doesn't do anything (it just raises the error); you'd - of course - do something smart and then raise the exception if something wrong happens
exception handling section specifically handles ex_sku; extract only desired part of the sqlerrm function result (i.e. remove everything that precedes the colon sign, and that's ORA-20001) and put the result into the hidden P4_ERROR_MESSAGE item
"Success message" process property should be set to &P4_ERROR_MESSAGE. (literally ampersand followed by item name followed by the dot)

When you run the page and press the "Run" button, result is:

It would've been better if you could use "Error message" property instead, but Help says that

This message displays if an unhandled exception is raised.

which is NOT what we have - this is a handled exception, so "Error message" just won't display it.
